# SD card History

Tags: terminal, usb, memory

I have lost my SD card. I want to know when it has been used last. 
Is there a way of showing up when which sd or usb device has been conectet to the mac ? Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 0):

Most activity like this will be logged in `/var/log/system.log`.

You can use `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app` to view the logs and search for specific messages - most disks would be mounted under /Volumes, so that's a good keyword to start looking for/

By default your system logs will go back about a week or so.